# Use jack os x in a sandbox Mac application

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, jack

On my Mac OS X application released on the App Store, I want to be able to use a [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com) audio device as an input but the device does not appear in the list returned by portaudio. When checking the logs in the console I see:

> 31/01/2014 10:11:35.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: MyApp(xxx) deny network-outbound /private/tmp/jack_default_501_0

Is there some extra permission I should add to my `entitlements` file to be able to access this device properly? This device properly appears/works when using testing my app without the sandbox enabled.